# Python Test grading program not quite working but close

Tags: python, file, for-loop, while-loop

I'm working on a program that opens a file 'answer.txt'. The file simulates a students answers to a test. This program then compares the file to the answerKey. It prints line by line the answerkey vs the students answer. It keeps count of good and bad answers. In the end it prints a score. I can get this program to work with two different answerkeys but when I try to pull the answers from the file I get too much output. It skips the first answer in the file. It then prints only B, D from answer key back and forth. The student side prints starting at the second answer and then skips every other answer.

My code:

```
def main():
    try:
        answerKey = ['B', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'C',\
                 'D', 'A', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'A']
        index = 0
        numCorrect = 0
        answer_file = open('answers.txt', 'r')

        studentExam = answer_file.readline()

        print('Correct\tYour\tStatus\nAns.\tAns.\n-----------------------\n')
        while studentExam != "":
            problem_number = index + 1
            studentExam = studentExam.rstrip("\n")

            studentExam = answer_file.readline()

            for answerLine, studentLine in zip (answerKey, studentExam):
                answer = answerLine.split()
                studentAnswer = studentLine.split()

                if studentAnswer != answer:
                    print( 'You got that question number', index + 1, 'wrong\n the correct answer was' ,answer, 'but you answered' , studentAnswer)
                    index += 1
                else:
                    numCorrect += 1
                    index += 1

        grade = int((numCorrect / 20) * 100)

        print (' The number of correctly answered questions: ', numCorrect)

        print (' The number of incorrectly answered questions: ', 20 - numCorrect)

        print (' Your grade is', grade, '%')

        if grade <= 75:
                    print (' You have not passed ')
        else:
                    print (' Congrats you have passed ')
    except IOError:
        print("The file could not be found")
    except IndexError:
        print("There was an indexing error")
    except:
        print("An error occurred")
main()
```

My output:

```
You got that question number 1 wrong
 the correct answer was ['B'] but you answered ['D']

You got that question number 2 wrong
the correct  answer was ['D'] but you answered []

You got that question number 3 wrong
 the correct answer was ['B'] but you answered ['A']

You got that question number 4 wrong
 the correct answer was ['D'] but you answered []

You got that question number 5 wrong
 the correct answer was ['B'] but you answered ['A']

You got that question number 6 wrong
 the correct answer was ['D'] but you answered []

You got that question number 7 wrong
 the correct answer was ['B'] but you answered ['C']

You got that question number 8 wrong
 the correct answer was ['D'] but you answered []

You got that question number 9 wrong
 the correct answer was ['B'] but you answered ['A']

You got that question number 10 wrong
 the correct answer was ['D'] but you answered []

You got that question number 12 wrong
 the correct answer was ['D'] but you answered []

You got that question number 13 wrong
 the correct answer was ['B'] but you answered ['A']

You got that question number 14 wrong
 the correct answer was ['D'] but you answered []

You got that question number 15 wrong
 the correct answer was ['B'] but you answered ['C']

You got that question number 16 wrong
 the correct answer was ['D'] but you answered []

You got that question number 17 wrong
 the correct answer was ['B'] but you answered ['C']

You got that question number 18 wrong
 the correct answer was ['D'] but you answered []

You got that question number 19 wrong
 the correct answer was ['B'] but you answered ['C']

You got that question number 20 wrong
 the correct answer was ['D'] but you answered []

You got that question number 21 wrong
 the correct answer was ['B'] but you answered ['C']

You got that question number 22 wrong
 the correct answer was ['D'] but you answered []

You got that question number 23 wrong
 the correct answer was ['B'] but you answered ['D']

You got that question number 24 wrong
 the correct answer was ['D'] but you answered []

You got that question number 25 wrong
 the correct answer was ['B'] but you answered ['A']

You got that question number 26 wrong
 the correct answer was ['D'] but you answered []

You got that question number 27 wrong
 the correct answer was ['B'] but you answered ['D']

You got that question number 28 wrong
 the correct answer was ['D'] but you answered []

You got that question number 29 wrong
 the correct answer was ['B'] but you answered ['C']

You got that question number 30 wrong
 the correct answer was ['D'] but you answered []

You got that question number 31 wrong
 the correct answer was ['B'] but you answered ['C']

You got that question number 32 wrong
 the correct answer was ['D'] but you answered []

You got that question number 34 wrong
 the correct answer was ['D'] but you answered []

You got that question number 35 wrong
 the correct answer was ['B'] but you answered ['D']

You got that question number 36 wrong
 the correct answer was ['D'] but you answered []

You got that question number 37 wrong
 the correct answer was ['B'] but you answered ['D']

You got that question number 38 wrong
 the correct answer was ['D'] but you answered []

 The number of correctly answered questions:  2
 The number of incorrectly answered questions:  18
 Your grade is 10 %
```

It's not comparing the right data, please help me correct this issue. There are only 20 answers, and the answers in the file look like:

```
B
D
A
A
C
A
B
A
C
C
C
C
D
A
D
C
C
B
D
D
```

Each in it's own line. So I'm trying to use a loop to go through each answer in the answer key and compare it to each answer from this file. Can anyone show me what's wrong in my python code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of iterating through the file, read the file in all at once into a list.  You then also want to sanitize the line of data.  This is accomplished by the following:

```
answers = open('answers.txt', 'r').readlines()
answers = [answer.strip() for answer in answers]
```

This makes your `while` loop moot, since all of that work is accounted for.

Once we have that, it's a matter of using that list.

```
for answerLine, studentLine in zip(answerKey, answers):
```

This will give you the following output (if placed properly):

```
Correct    Your    Status
Ans.    Ans.
-----------------------

('You got that question number', 10, 'wrong\n the correct answer was', ['D'], 'but you answered', ['C'])
('You got that question number', 11, 'wrong\n the correct answer was', ['B'], 'but you answered', ['C'])
('You got that question number', 20, 'wrong\n the correct answer was', ['A'], 'but you answered', ['D'])
(' The number of correctly answered questions: ', 17)
(' The number of incorrectly answered questions: ', 3)
(' Your grade is', 85, '%')
Congrats you have passed
```

Also, I **strongly** discourage the use of an empty `except` block.  This will make debugging your code a nightmare, since you won't be able to pinpoint what could have gone wrong and where.

Comment: Thank you. I'm actually using this for a programming class but I'm ahead of the class and the book was not explaining this program very clearly, but your input really helped. I wouldn't normally put an empty except block but the teacher requested it. I usually turn it off as a comment while I'm working on the program or code it to display the actual error to make debugging easier. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is not what you expect.  You are looping through the file using `readline`, then for every line in that file you are trying to loop over the answer key.  Each line in the file returns two characters (`'B\n'`) which is the grade and the newline character.  When you do the `for answerLine, studentLine in zip (answerKey, studentExam):` line, you are `zip`ing the long answer key with the 2-element studentExam (remember that strings are iterable), and thus you see just the first who answer keys (and the second one has a blank student answer.

What I recommend is reading in the student's answers all at once at the beginning of your algorithm, then use `zip` on that full list.  That will give you what you want.

P.S., you probably want this:

```
answer = answerLine.strip()
studentAnswer = studentLine.strip()
```

instead of this:

```
answer = answerLine.split()
studentAnswer = studentLine.split()
```

Comment: Thanks I just started working with these algorithms and still getting the hang of it. Still a programming n00b but learning and this info really helped in fixing this program. More importantly explaining the issue really helped so I can understand why the loop is acting the way it is. Thanks and I'll set it up to open the file all at once and zip on the full list.